# How to upload Multiple Images Of same product using CSV FIle in magento 2.0?

Tags: magento2, product-images, image, csv

I am Trying to upload Multiple image of same product in magento 2 using csv file. I am adding one image each on  base_image, small_image, and thumbnail_image and other remaining images on additional_images .But after importing it is giving an Error :-

> Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external
>   resource due to timeout or access permissions,General system exception
>   happened.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: I think,  you need to add  all product images to this path  `mageto2root/pub/media/import` then import

Comment: Can you provide me sample code ?? I am looking for same.

Comment: Please show screenshot of excel csv file, so that we can see if you doing any , comma related syntax error...

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload all your images on a specific folder, for example :

```
{Magento_Root_Path}/var/import/images
```

Make sure than your web-server user has the **correct permission** on this folder and on all of the image files.

Than process a product import from the back-office and fill the correct path for the image folder.